# Check if JSONArray is actually integer of boolean array

Tags: java, json

Is it possible to check if JSONArray is actually boolean or integer array. I've searched trough internet for hours but I can't find anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `instanceof` on the first element:

```
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject("{ \"a1\": [ false, true, false, true ], \"a2\": [1,2,3,4] }");
    JSONArray a1 = o.getJSONArray("a1");
    JSONArray a2 = o.getJSONArray("a2");
    if (a1.length() > 0) {
        if (a1.get(0) instanceof Boolean) {
            System.out.println("a1 is Boolean array");
        } else if (a1.get(0) instanceof Integer) {
            System.out.println("a1 is Integer array");
        } else {
            System.out.println("a1 is some other type");
        }
    }
    if (a2.length() > 0) {
        if (a2.get(0) instanceof Boolean) {
            System.out.println("a2 is Boolean array");
        } else if (a2.get(0) instanceof Integer) {
            System.out.println("a2 is Integer array");
        } else {
            System.out.println("a2 is some other type");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `JSONArray` from `org.json` package then you can do 2 things.
1) you can use `optBoolean` or `optInt` methods which return true if value is boolean or int respectively, as doc says [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#optBoolean%28int%29)
2) you can get JSONArray value in Object and check its instance by instanceOf keyword and then use appropriately.